# Bringing tables within page margin

Tags: tables, margins, bad-box

[image]
I want to bring these two tables close to each other so that these do not cross the page margins.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4size]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}[ht!]
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                        \hline
                        $\wedge$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
                        \hline
                        $\phi$ & $\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$\\
                        \hline
                        $a$ &$\phi$ &\{a\} &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$\\
                        \hline
                        $b$ &$\phi$ &$\phi$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{b\}$ \\
                        \hline
                        $\{a,b\}$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \caption{Composition table for meet}
            \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                        \hline
                        $\vee$ &$\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
                        \hline
                        $\phi$ & $\phi$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
                        \hline
                        $a$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{a\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$\\
                        \hline
                        $b$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
                        \hline
                        $\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ &$\{a,b\}$ \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \caption{Composition table for join}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have used `begin{center}...\end{center}` but this places the tables vertically which I don't want. The bad box comment is `Overfull \hbox (4.24258pt too wide) in paragraph`

Comment: Your MWE currently is not compilable. `\begin{document}` is missing here and you probably wanted to use `\documentclass[12pt,a4size]{article}` instead of `\documentclass{12pt,a4size}{article}`. If I correct these two issues, I get a different output than the one you show in your question.

Comment: Regarding the issue itself, you might want to start by placing a `%` right after the first `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: Also, remove the `\\ ` from both captions.

Comment: if I remove  \\  from the first caption, the below part of the caption exceeds the `Table 1`

Comment: What about one of the following three version? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvdPY.png

Comment: Table 3,4,5,6 are good

Comment: @leandriis i have just edited my question by including `%` right after the first `\end{minipage}` and changed `.5\textwidth` to `.45\textwidth`. But this actually messed the captions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small variation of @leandriis answer (+1): using `array` instead of `tabular`, estimated column width:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{array} % for wc type column

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
    \[
\begin{array}{|*{5}{wc{2.2em}|}}
    \hline
\wedge  & \phi  & \{a\} & \{b\} & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
\phi    & \phi  & \phi  & \phi  & \phi      \\
    \hline
a       &\phi   &\{a\}  & \phi  & \{a\}     \\
    \hline
b       &\phi   &\phi   & \{b\} & \{b\}     \\
    \hline
\{a,b\} & \phi  &\{a\}  & \{b\} & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
\end{array}
    \]
\caption{Composition table for meet}
\label{tab:meet}
    \end{minipage}%
\hfil%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \[
\begin{array}{|*{5}{wc{2.2em}|}}
    \hline
\vee    & \phi      & \{a\}     & \{b\}     & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
\phi    & \phi      & \{a\}     & \{b\}     & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
a       & \{a\}     & \{a\}     & \{a,b\}   & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
b       & \{b\}     & \{a,b\}   & \{b\}     & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
\{a,b\} & \{a,b\}   & \{a,b\}   & \{a,b\}   & \{a,b\}   \\
    \hline
\end{array}
    \]
\caption{Composition table for join}
\label{tab:join}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions of your table . In both versions, I made sure that all columns in both tables are equally wide. For this, I used the `\widhtof` command from the `calc` package in combination with the `wc{...}` column type from the `array` package. In order to save typing `$...$` in all cells of the table, I also added `>{$}` and `<{$}` to the column definition in both tables. Additionally, I decreased the width of both minipages slightly in order to prevent overlapping captions. I chose a width of `0.475\textwidth` since this width allows both captions to still fit into a single line.

Having applied these changes, both tables are now too wide to fit into their respective minipages. In order to overcome this, I decreased the value of `\tabcolsep` (horizontal white space between a vertical line and the start/end of the cell's actual contents) from its default value of `6pt` to `4pt`. With this change, both tables now easily fit into their minipages:

[image]

Since the horizontal lines are quite close to the contents of the cells, I used `\makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package in order to symmetrically increase the row heights for an alternative output:

[image]

Since both captions of the tables are almost identical, you could probably also use a single shared caption for both of them:

[image]

I also included the code for this third version in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} % Replaced unknown option a4size with a4paper
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{array} % Necessary for >{>$}  and the wc type column
\usepackage{calc} % necessary for the \widthof command
\usepackage{makecell} % Only needed to symmetrically increase row heights
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\begin{document}
        
        \begin{table}[ht!]
        %\makegapedcells % optional. uncomment if you want to get the second output with increased row heights.
         \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
            \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{$}wc{\widthof{\{a,b\}}}<{$}|}}
                        \hline
                        \wedge &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                        \hline
                        \phi & \phi &\phi &\phi &\phi\\
                        \hline
                        a &\phi &\{a\} &\phi &\{a\}\\
                        \hline
                        b &\phi &\phi &\{b\} &\{b\} \\
                        \hline
                        \{a,b\} &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \caption{Composition table for meet}
            \end{minipage} \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
            \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{$}wc{\widthof{\{a,b\}}}<{$}|}}
                        \hline
                        \vee &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                        \hline
                        \phi & \phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                        \hline
                        a &\{a\} &\{a\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                        \hline
                        b &\{b\} &\{a,b\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                        \hline
                        \{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \caption{Composition table for join}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{table}


\begin{table}[ht!]
\makegapedcells % optional. uncomment if you want to get the second output with increased row heights.
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
  \caption{Composition tables for meet (left) and join (right)}
            \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{$}wc{\widthof{\{a,b\}}}<{$}|}}
                \hline
                \wedge &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                \hline
                \phi & \phi &\phi &\phi &\phi\\
                \hline
                a &\phi &\{a\} &\phi &\{a\}\\
                \hline
                b &\phi &\phi &\{b\} &\{b\} \\
                \hline
                \{a,b\} &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{$}wc{\widthof{\{a,b\}}}<{$}|}}
                \hline
                \vee &\phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                \hline
                \phi & \phi &\{a\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                \hline
                a &\{a\} &\{a\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\}\\
                \hline
                b &\{b\} &\{a,b\} &\{b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                \hline
                \{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} &\{a,b\} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```